# Android: RPC calls over the internet

Tags: android, rpc

hi im quite new to android development and am coming from the world of GWT and Remote procedure calls to communicate with a server.

Now i am looking for a way to realize calls on a server over the internet via my android app.

is there a pretty way to realize this?

thanks in advance

Edit: Okay maybe I put my question wrong. I am just looking for a way to send a class object from my server via an appropriate protocol over the internet, so i can use it in my app

can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you using HTTP? What protocol?

Comment: yes i think i would prefer http. i found a way to realize it but i am not really satisfied with it. the way i do it now is: i use xstream to make an xml file out of the object, i want to send. then send it and then use xstream again to turn the sent xml file back into the object inside the app. but there must be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http-dispatch. It is the adapted gwt-dispatch framework which can be used on Android platform. Http-dispatch uses default binary serialization so it works from the box for many types of objects. Currently it is in alpha but you can try http://code.google.com/p/http-dispatch/